# Prevent Windows PC from waking up by wireless mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, sleep, wake-up

I have a wireless mouse that is connected to the PC using a Bluetooth USB receiver. Whenever my laptop is sleeping with the lid closed, a slight movement of the mouse wakes my laptop. Any way to disable that? I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: This would be done in Device Manager for that specific device. Find that mouse device in device manager, double click on it and go to the power management tab, untick the "allow this device to wake the computer"

Comment: I tried this for HID-compliant mouse. It didn't work.

Comment: Did you restart your PC after the change?

Comment: Try to find the usb receiver in DM, see if there is a power management tab.

Answer (score 1):

In the Device Manager, disable a keyboard device's ability to wake up the computer (`HID Keyboard Device`).

There might be multiple keyboards, so you will have to try until you find the right one.

[image: device manager with HID Keyboard Device properties visible]

One can speculate why mice can be listed as keyboards. For example: this might be because the wireless receiver supports both mice and keyboards.

Since it might be a bit hard to believe, here's a demonstration video: [Prevent Wireless Mouse from Waking Up Windows from Sleep Mode](https://youtu.be/75BpfWqy99o).

This solution was found thanks to [Windows 10 -- Cannot disable the mouse from waking computer from sleep) from 2015](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-cannot-disable-the-mouse-from-waking/706340c2-1fcc-4cd0-b747-c736d8a31b34).